# Whats the 'Ruby way' to identify duplicate values in a hash?

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I'm on Ruby 2.7.x on macOS Catalina.

I have up to 1 million key value tuples.
The keys are strings and are guaranteed unique.
The values are strings and may contain duplicates (or triplicates or more).
Given the uniqueness of the keys, it seems that a hash is a natural data structure for them.
So if I start with original_hash, containing all the key value tuples,
I'd like to end up with uniques_hash, containing all and only unique key value tuples,
and duplicates_hash, containing all the keys with duplicated values.

I am more interested in optimising for clarity and Ruby idiom than memory efficiency or speed - I don't expect to be running this code frequently, and I have plenty of RAM.

If I convert to two arrays, I can find the uniques in the values array - but how do I guarantee re-pairing with the correct key? And is that the right way to approach this problem?

Many thanks for any assistance!

Comment: have you got any code, or examples of the data you're looking at?

Comment: Please include an example. If your hash were `{ :a=>1, :b=>1}` would you want your `uniques_hash` to equal `{ :a=>1}` or `{:b=>1}`?

Comment: jad, Cary - thanks for engaging! The keys are filepaths, eg photos/3 May 2009/ IMG_4588.jpg and so on. I'm generating a list of filepaths by walking a directory structure, so I know they're unique. The values are hex digests, generated from the filepath by Digest::SHA512.hexdigest File.read  . So, if my directory structure contains 2 or more copies of the same photo, I will have duplicate values. What I want to do is (eventually) copy the directory structure to one that contains one copy of every file, and another that contains only duplicate copies. @Cary - I don't care which one!

Answer (score 3):

Suppose

```
original_hash = {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>2, :d=>2, :e=>3, :f=>4, :g=>4}
```

If you were only interested in returning a hash `uniques_hash` that contained unique values, you could write the following.

```
uniques_hash = original_hash.invert.invert
  #=> {:a=>1, :d=>2, :e=>3, :g=>4}
```

the intermediate step being

```
original_hash.invert
  #=> {1=>:a, 2=>:d, 3=>:e, 4=>:g}
```

See [Hash#invert](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-invert). Note that `uniques_hash`, as defined, is not itself unique. It could be any of the following.

```
{:a=>1, :b=>2, :e=>3, :f=>4}
{:a=>1, :b=>2, :e=>3, :g=>4}
{:a=>1, :c=>2, :e=>3, :f=>4}
{:a=>1, :c=>2, :e=>3, :g=>4}
{:a=>1, :d=>2, :e=>3, :f=>4}
{:a=>1, :d=>2, :e=>3, :g=>4}
```

Another way of doing this is to use [Enumerable#uniq](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-uniq) and [Array#to_h](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-to_h).

```
unique_hash = original_hash.uniq(&:last).to_h
  #=> {:a=>1, :b=>2, :e=>3, :f=>4}
```

the intermediate calculation being

```
original_hash.uniq(&:last)
  #=> [[:a, 1], [:b, 2], [:e, 3], [:f, 4]]
```

which is shorthand for

```
original_hash.uniq { |_k,v| v }
```

---

Presumably, each key of `duplicates_hash` is a value in `original_hash` and the value of that key is an array of those keys `k` in `original_hash` for which `original_hash[k] == v`.

One way to compute `duplicates_hash` is as follows.

```
duplicates_hash = original_hash.each_with_object({}) do |(k,v),h|
  h[v] = (h[v] || []) << k
end
  #=> {1=>[:a], 2=>[:b, :c, :d], 3=>[:e], 4=>[:f, :g]}
```

This can also be written

```
duplicates_hash = original_hash.
  each_with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }) { |(k,v),h| h[v] << k }
  #=> {1=>[:a], 2=>[:b, :c, :d], 3=>[:e], 4=>[:f, :g]}
```

See [Hash::new](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-c-new). Both forms are equivalent to

```
duplicates_hash = original_hash.each_with_object({}) do |(k,v),h|
  h[v] = [] unless h.key?(v)
  h[v] << k
end
```

Writing the block variables as `|(k,v),h|` makes use of [array decomposition](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.7.0/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Array+Decomposition).

We have an enumerator that will generate values and pass them to its block.

```
enum = original_hash.each_with_object({})
  #=> #<Enumerator: {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>2, :d=>2, :e=>3, :f=>4, :g=>4}:
  #     each_with_object({})>
```

Enumerators are instances of the class [Enumerator](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerator.html).

The first value of the enumerator is generated and the block variables are assigned values like so:

```
(k,v),h = enum.next
  #=> [[:a, 1], {}]
```

Array decomposition is seen to split this array of two elements as follows:

```
k #=> :a 
v #=> 1 
h #=> {}
```

Notice how the parentheses on the left correspond to the inner brackets on the right. The block calculation is then performed using these variables.

```
h[v] = (h[v] || []) << k
  #=> [:a]
```

Now,

```
h #=> {1=>[:a]}
```

The next value is then generated by the enumerator and the block calculation is performed.

```
(k,v),h = enum.next
  #=> [[:b, 2], {1=>[:a]}] 
k #=> :b 
v #=> 2 
h #=> {1=>[:a]} 
h[v] = (h[v] || []) << k
```

so now

```
h #=> {1=>[:a], 2=>[:b]}
```

This continues until

```
enum.next
  #=> Stop Interation (exception)
```

causing Ruby to return the value of `h`.

---

Note that by computing `duplicates_hash` first we could compute `uniques_hash` as follows.

```
keeper_keys = duplicates_hash.values.map(&:first)
  #=> [:a, :b, :e, :f] 
unique_keys = original_hash.slice(*keeper_keys)
  #=> {:a=>1, :b=>2, :e=>3, :f=>4}
```

or

```
unique_keys = original_hash.slice(*duplicates_hash.values.map(&:first))
  #=> {:a=>1, :b=>2, :e=>3, :f=>4}
```

See [Hash#slice](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-slice). If one feels guilty by favouring certain keys one could instead write

```
unique_keys = original_hash.slice(*duplicates_hash.values.map(&:sample))
  #=> {:a=>1, :b=>2, :e=>3, :g=>4}
```

See [Array#sample](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-sample).

Comment: Cary, many thanks for this. The double invert is clever and  I'll work through the rest.  As may be obvious, I'm a rank beginner at this!

Answer (score 2):

it might or might not be the best way to go about this, but I've used the "group_by" and "select" functions to get me a new hash that finds duplicates:

```
hash.group_by{|k,v| v}.select{|k,v| v.count > 1}
```

in this case, the returned hash will look a bit like:

```
{value: [{key: value}, {key: value}]}
```

Comment: jad - super, looks like 'group_by' gets me to where I want to be!

Answer (score 1):

Count the values using [`group_by`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/group_by) and store the results in a hash. Use that hash to [`partition`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/partition) the original hash like so:

```
h = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 2, d: 2, e: 3, f: 4, g: 4}

cnt = Hash[h.values.group_by{ |i| i }.map { |k, v| [k, v.count] }]
h_uniq, h_dups = h.partition{ |k, v| cnt[v] == 1 }.map(&:to_h)

puts cnt
# {1=>1, 2=>3, 3=>1, 4=>2}

puts h_uniq.inspect
# {:a=>1, :e=>3}

puts h_dups.inspect
# {:b=>2, :c=>2, :d=>2, :f=>4, :g=>4}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all for the help on this! I thought it might help someone if I posted my draft code, and any comments /improvements are very welcome! (I'm in the process of refactoring Listing..)
N

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# shebang to run the script from Terminal

# include shasum
require 'digest'

class Listing
  # class of arrays of file listings 
attr_reader :path
  def initialize(path)
    @path = path
    Dir.chdir(@path)
    @list_of_items = Dir['**/*']
    @list_of_folders = []
    @list_of_files = []
    @list_of_extensions = []
    @list_of_uniques = []
    @list_of_duplicates = []
  end

  def to_s
    "#{@path}"
  end
  
  def analyse_items
    @list_of_items.each do |f|
      if File.directory?(f)
        @list_of_folders << f
      else
        @list_of_files << f
      end
    end
    @list_of_folders.sort!
    @list_of_files.sort!
    @folder_count = @list_of_folders.count
    @files_count = @list_of_files.count
    @items_count = @list_of_items.count
    @count_check = (@items_count -(@folder_count + @files_count))
    # count_check should be zero
  end

  def identify_duplicates
    # Given an array of filepaths, this method divides it into an array of unique files and an array of duplicated files.  
    source = {}
    uniques = {}
        
    @list_of_files.each do |f|
      digest = Digest::SHA512.hexdigest File.read f
      source.store(f, digest)
    end
    
    uniques = source.invert.invert
    @list_of_uniques = uniques.keys
    @list_of_duplicates = source.keys - uniques.keys
  end
  
  def tell_duplicates
    puts "dupes = #{@list_of_duplicates}"
  end
    
end
 


l = Listing.new("/Volumes/Things/Photos/")
l.analyse_items
l.identify_duplicates
l.tell_duplicates
```